# how to share each article to facebook

Tags: php

I need to keep facebook like and share for each individual articles posted by various users. Once i logged in to the site and give share to the particular article it should get shared in facebook as well as it should show the count near to the share button of that individual article.....below is my coding please help me to get rid of this problem.Thanks a lot!

```
function selfURL() {
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : ""; 
    $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s; 
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);    
    return 

$protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
} 

function strleft($s1, $s2) { 
    return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2)); 
}

<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=204703199589477&amp;xfbml=1">
</script>
<fb:like href="<?php print(selfURL()); ?>" send="false" width="90" show_faces="false" action="like" font="" layout="button_count">
</fb:like>
</div>
```

Comment: If you format your code, we may read the question.

Comment: Are you using the Facebook JavaScript SDK on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Include the JavaScript on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=182934585182826";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.test.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Replace `http://test.com` with the URL of your Article. If you pase the DIV 3 time

As for the Share button, you'll need this piece of script. Yet again, change the domain to your article url

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://example.com"></div>
```